# Is it still possible to connect to Yahoo XMPP transports?

Tags: xmpp, jabber, yahoo-messenger

I am not able to connect to Yahoo XMPP (jabber) transports.

The error message reads 'Account locked: You have been logging in too frequently.  Wait a few minutes before trying to connect again.  Logging into the Yahoo! website may help.'

I tried at least two different XMPP servers having a Yahoo transport, and the same thing happens.

My client is Gajim 0.15

Comment: you must do what they say. Log in the yahoo website.